# trouble decoding url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am urlencoding a url string using php and then passing it via curl to a phantomjs script where I am trying to decode it using javascript.

I am starting with:

```
localhost:7788/hi there/how are you/
```

which gets turned into:

```
 localhost:7788/hi+there%2Fhow+are+you
```

on the php side by the urlencode() function.

On the phantomjs side , I have:

```
// Create serever and listen port 
server.listen(port, function(request, response) {    

function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}    


        // Print some information Just for debbug 
        console.log("We got some requset !!!"); 
        console.log("request method: ", request.method);  // request.method POST or GET 
        console.log("Get params: ", request.url); //     

           url= urldecode(request.url);

        //-- Split requested params
      var requestparams = request.url.split('/');    


      console.log(urldecode(requestparams[1]));
      console.log(urldecode(requestparams[2]));
```

The output at the console is :

```
.....
request method:  GET
Get params:  /hi%2Bthere/how%2Bare%2Byou
hi+there
how+are+you
```

Why are the '+' signs not replaced with spaces? I'm trying to get rid of them and it looks to me that the function 'urldecode' should do this.

Comment: Why are there '+'-signs in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) instead of `urlencode()` in the PHP side, so spaces are encoded with `%20` and not`+` signs, so javascript can decode them well with `decodeURIComponent()`.